# Can't find the right regex to fit pattern

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to format a play in Emacs. The dialogs look like this :

```
<speaker>Madelon</speaker>

Mon Dieu, que vous êtes vulgaire ! Pour moi, un de mes étonnements,
c'est que vous ayez pu faire une fille si spirituelle que moi. A-t-on
jamais parlé, dans le beau style, de Cathos ni de Madelon, et ne
m'avouerez-vous pas que ce serait assez d'un de ces noms pour décrier
le plus beau roman du monde ?

<speaker>Cathos</speaker>
```

My goal is to capture the whole dialog, so everything that is not inside the `<speaker>` tag.

The problem is that I can only manage to get the first line, with this RegEx :

```
/speaker>\n\n\[A-Z].*\n
```

I can also get the second line, like this :

```
/speaker>\n\n\[A-Z].*\n.*\n
```

But that's not really convenient. I'm stuck after this, because when I try

```
/speaker>\n\n\[A-Z][.*\n]+
```

It doesn't match with anything. Shouldn't the `[.*\n]+` mean that I want one or more of "any number of characters followed by a newline"?

Cheers

Comment: *Shouldn't the `[.*\n]+` mean that I want one or more of "any number of characters followed by a newline"?* No, it means "One or more of these characters: `.`, `*`, `\ `, or `n`."

Comment: I don't understand the requirement.  You say "everything that is not inside the <speaker> tag" and yet in your own tests you are including (a part of) the speaker tag. Can you please elaborate on (a) exactly which text you are trying to match, and (b) exactly how the regexp is being *used* (as this may inform the most sensible approach).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=<\/speaker>)([^<]*)(?=(<speaker>|\n))`](https://regex101.com/r/jhe6dP/2)

- `(?<=<\/speaker>)` makes sure `</speaker>` is before your match
- `([^<]*)` matches anything until a `<`
- `(?=(<speaker>|\n))` makes sure `<speaker>` or a newline is after your match

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/jhe6dP/2)

Comment: This is not an Emacs-compatible regexp (and not merely on account of syntax differences -- arbitrary zero-width look-ahead/behind assertions are not available at all).

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me, what it is you more precisely want to achieve, that is, what the end result is going to be. Regexps has a number of important limitations if wanting to work with long stretches of text and/or repeated text.

If you just want the dialog without any speaker notes, and all speakers are on a line by itself, you can quickly delete all of the command `flush-lines`. This takes a regexp and deletes all lines that contains that line. (There is also an inverse command called `keep-lines` that delete everything that does *not* contain a given regex.)

If you something fancier, where speakers notations is somehow folded into the dialog, you could consider a keyboard macro. You start recording by typing `C-x (` and end recording by typing `C-x )`. Then you can repeat the keyboard macro by typing `C-x e`. The trick to making it work, is by typing commands that assumes as little as possible about the text, in order for it to work efficiently across all instances of what it is you want to edit. It takes some practice and is greatly aided by knowing about commands such as `forward-word` and `forward-sexp` to make movement more resilient.